# MacMini Shared Folder Slow Speeds

Tags: network, mac-mini, sharing

I have a macmini that I am trying to use as a file server.

I have setup a shared directory and have enabled sharing (SMB, AFP and enabled Windows Sharing).

I can now connect to this drive on my LAN, but the transfer speeds are really slow, between 2.5 and 3.5 MB/sec.

Is there anyway or any settings that can be used to improve file transfer speeds?

**Updated Information**

Both computers are connected via WiFi using a **TP-Link AC1200 Dual Band Gigabit Router**

The Mac-Mini server has a transmission rate of 145 Mbps or ~17.3 MiB/s

The Windows 7 client has a speed of 144 Mbps or ~17.2 MiB/s

Comment: Is this speed slow using any of the protocols or just one?

Comment: I should have added. I am connecting from a Windows 7 machine to the Mac-Mini. I am pretty sure this means that it is a SMB connection.

Comment: So try ftp or afp connection to get more idea of where the issue is

Comment: Tried an FTP upload, and had a similar cap of around 3.5 MB/sec.

Comment: How are the two devices (Mac Mini and Windows 7 computer) connected? On your Mac right click on your network icon while holding Option on your keyboard and see what it says next to "Transmit Rate"? Then on your Windows computer right click on your Network Status icon and select Status then in there see what your "Speed:" says? Whichever of these is the lowest is your maximum transfer speed in Mbits (Mbps) per second. To convert this to MBytes (MBps) per second go to [Google](https://www.google.com/) and type in "##Mbps to MiBps" (don't forget the i) to see your maximum speed in MBps.

Comment: On the Windows-7 machine the speed is 144 Mbps and on the Mac-Mini it is 145 Mbps. Which according to google is 1098.63 and 1106.26 respectively. They are both connected via WiFi using a **TP-Link AC1200 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router**.

Comment: @stats 144 Mb/s are 18 MB/s or ~17.2 MiB/s (and 14.4 MB/s or ~13.7 MiB/s (8b10b))

Comment: Thank you for the edit. A 3.5 MB/s max speed still seems slow to me. Overhead is expected. So an actual speed 8 or 9 MB/s is what I might expect. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct it is slow (also seems Google's converter is being a little weird today) my Late 2006 iMac is connected at 270Mbps/32MBps and I just tested uploading to my network drive (which is only USB 2.0) and it stayed a constant 20MBps, most likely because of the USB 2.0 is why it's not faster. I would add in that I have a rather high end router but it sounds like yours is just as fast. My next suggestion would be try connecting either the PC or the Mac to ethernet and see if speeds improve at all. Are you in a busy place like an apartment with a ton of nearby networks?